# how i retrive the data in edit text from shared preference?

Tags: android

Hi all can anyone tell me hod do i get the saved data in edit text after saving that , i mean when i save some text then i want that text will appear in edit text all the time Thanks.
Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private EditText inputName;
    private TextInputLayout inputLayoutName;
    private Button btnSave;

    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    public static final String Message = "nameKey";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        inputLayoutName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_name);
       inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_message);
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);

        inputName.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputName));
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String m  = inputName.getText().toString();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

                editor.putString(Message, m);
                editor.apply();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank You!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you make a bit clearer please ? Text does remain in EditText unless you explicitly remove it from the keyboard. What precisely is it that your require ? Are you shifting between activities and expecting the Text to fill up automatically in the EditText once to go the relevant Activity ?

Comment: `inputText.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Message, ""));`

Answer (score 2):

```
inputName.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Message, "default_value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String m  = inputName.getText().toString();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

                    editor.putString(Message, m);
                    editor.apply();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank You!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    inputName.setText(m, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE); //set the text here
                }
            });
```